# Create Asterisk config

Tags: asterisk

I have to build Asterisk on my own on Debian 12.

As part of the installation, Asterisk offers to generate a large amount of long config files in `/etc/asterisk`, incluing an example PBX scenario (e.g. sales department etc.).

What is the recommended approach to get your Asterisk config?

Use all the generated files and comment out / delete all the stuff you don't need?

Or start with empty files and only put your configuration into and rely on defaults for stuff not explicitely configured?

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: That's up to your personal preference.